# Determine commits introduced to branch by merge commit in git?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-log, git-rev-list

I am trying to determine commits introduced to parent branch due to a merge using merge id.

Answer (score 2):

Command `git log <id>~1..<id>` will list you all merged commits, and the merge commit itself.

Comment: This is the way to go for any real merge.  If you want to exclude the merge itself, use `id^1..id^2`.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Use [max630's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49229960/1256452), as long as it's a real merge.  To exclude the merge itself, use a slight variant of it: `M^1..M^2`.

#### Long

What you are asking for here is to find commits that became *reachable* as a result of the merge.  This *reachability* idea is a graph-theory concept.  Thus, if you draw the result of a merge, the answer is clearer.

#### Find the merge base(s)

Suppose the "before merge" graph looks like this, where `*` is the merge base commit and `L` and `R` are the left and right side tip commits:

```
...--*--...--L   <-- mainline
      \
       o--...--R   <-- sidebranch
```

Then the "after merge" graph looks like this:

```
...--*--...--L---M   <-- mainline
      \         /
       o--...--R   <-- sidebranch
```

The newly introduced commits are, now obviously, :-) the ones along the bottom row, i.e., those reachable from (and including) `R`, but excluding the merge base commit.  We reach them by starting from the second parent of `M`, which is `R`, then working along the backwards connections from `R` to its parent, to another parent, and so on.  These lead to the bottom `o` node, which connects back to commit `*`.

If you have a name like `sidebranch` pointing to `R`, you need only find the merge base:

```
mb=$(git merge-base $all mainline^1 sidebranch)
```

which uses the "first parent of the commit" syntax to identify commit `L` from commit `M`: the `^1` suffix.  If you no longer have the name `sidebranch`, you can identify commit `R` by using the "second parent of the commit" syntax:

```
mb=$(git merge-base $all mainline^1 mainline^2)
```

Unfortunately, that's not the only possible input graph.  It's quite typical to have a "before merge" graph that looks like this:

```
...--*   <-- mainline
      \
       o--...--R   <-- sidebranch
```

Running `git merge` without `--no-ff` will execute a "fast forward" operation, which is not actually a merge: you end up with a linear graph and no merge commit:

```
...--*--o--...--R   <-- mainline, sidebranch
```

Here, unless you still have the reflog entry for the main line branch, it is literally impossible to find commit `*`.  If you *do* have the reflog entry, it is trivial: it is `mainline@{number}`, using the appropriate *`number`*.  (Finding the appropriate *`number`* is a matter of looking through the reflog to find the update that is from a fast-forward.  If you just did the merge, it's simply `1` and is also `HEAD@{1}`.)

```
mb=$(git rev-parse mainline@{1})   # for instance
```

The reason I put `$all` in the example commands for finding the merge base above is that there's yet a third possibility, when you have multiple merge bases:

```
...--o--*---o--...--L
         \ /
          X
         / \
...--o--*---o--...--R
```

Here, you will want to exclude all the merge bases.  Replace `$all` with `--all` if necessary.

#### Now you have everything you need

Now that you know the merge base(s), having found them with `git merge-base` if the merge was a real merge, the commits that were made reachable by the merge are simply those reachable from `R` itself, but not from the merge base(s):

```
git rev-list sidebranch --not $mb
```

Use `git log` rather than `git rev-list` if you want to inspect the commits rather than simply enumerating them.

#### Simplifying this

All of the above is designed to find the merge base(s) and exclude them, so that we get commit `R` and its reachable ancestors without getting any commit reachable from `L`.  But we don't have to *start* this exclusion specifically from the merge base.  We can just start it from `L` itself.

To name `L`, we just need to name the previous value of `mainline` or the first parent of merge `M`.  The first parent of `M` is `M^1` or `M~1`, so as long as we know the hash ID of `M`, we can just add the suffix and say "exclude these".

There's even a short-hand syntax for this.  Instead of:

```
git rev-list M^2 --not M^1
```

or the slightly shorter:

```
git rev-list M^2 ^M^1
```

we can use the two-dot syntax:

```
git rev-list M^1..M^2
```

which is what we have at the top.

Note that all of this assumes "real merge": if the merge was a fast-forward, you must use the reflog instead.

Comment: Thank you for elaborated explanation. How do i compute in case of fast-forward merge??

Comment: That's where the stuff in the middle (not very well placed) comes in: you must use the reflog. If the information is to be found at all, that is where it will be found. Note that reflog entries eventually expire, and reflogs are not transported to clones of the repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout the branch and use git log to view the commits and the commit Id in the branch. 
`git log -n10 --oneline` will give you the history of previous 10 commits in that branch.